# One of the signing certificates from the MDM profile is expired.

Tags: ios, certificate, mdm

Is there a way that I can change only that expired certificate in the profile? 
Or 
I have to create a completely new profile?[image]

Comment: You'll have to sign it with the renewed certificate. So yes I believe you'll have to make a new profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to sign again the mdm profile with the new certificate.

Answer (score 0):

I had to sign it again with the new certificate.