# iOS MDM Certificates Expiry

Tags: ios, ssl, apple-push-notifications, mdm

I am creating an MDM Server and have successfully completed all the steps and was able to install the profile on the device.

In the .mobileconfig file which is installed on the device, we pass the SSL certificate, APNS certificate and profile information.

1) What if the SSL Certificate on the server is changed? (I guess this is not practiced by many or not practiced at all but still want to know what happens when this case occurs)

2) What happens after the APNS certificate is expired after one year?

How do I update the profiles on devices in which the profiles were already installed. Should the profiles be manually deleted and reinstalled or is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

1. Regarding the SSL certificate: 
   The mdm profile using the SSL certificate is not affected and can be continued to use. The only thing that will happen is on the device when you view the profile it will show that specific signing certificate to be expired.
   Solution: You need to sign the mdm profile again with the new certificate.
   Refer solution to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46587912/8472539).
2. You have option to renew the APNS certificate before it expires. Apple sends you email (to the apple-id that generated the APNS certificate) before the certificate expires. If you renew the certificate before expiration, you don't have to re-enroll the devices.
   In case the certificate is already expired, you need to create a new one using the same old apple-id and will have to re-enroll all the devices to receive the MDM push.

Comment: In the SSL Certificate case, how do I update the profile. Should the user delete the profile and install the new one?

Comment: Yes the user needs to delete the old profile and install the new one.
Re-enrolling the device also updates the profile. @HulkMan

Comment: and if the SSL Certificate expires, the profile will get updated automatically?

Comment: No the profile doesn't update automatically. User needs to install new one or re-enroll @HulkMan